# Detect if a .doc file is password protected on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, password-protection, doc

I have .doc file. I want to know is there is any shell/linux cmd that can tell whether the doc file is password protected or not.

For pdf files , I have got pdfinfo. Is there anything for .doc files.

Thanks

Comment: Try to open it in LibreOffice

Comment: Ok..is there any linux command to do that? with Libreoffice it will first try to open the files . I dont want to do that. I want just plain detection if the doc is password protected. just like pdfinfo

Answer (score 2):

Install `antiword`. If document is password protected, the output of `antiword file.doc` will be `Encrypted documents are not supported`, otherwise it will be content of the document.